# neo4j: alternative way for getProperty()

Tags: neo4j

I use getProperty(), but it's very slow way. Can I get property of the node without getProperty()? Maybe, exist some faster way?

Thanks!

UPD. Can I store property as an array and use like this: node.getProperty(i) where "i" - index of Array?

Comment: no, `getProperty` only takes property names which are strings. There is no faster way to get the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can show some code so we can pinpoint what's causing the slow responses.

You can only get properties with the *getProperty()* methods. Although you can save primitive arrays in Neo4j, there's no way of accessing it directly with an index (the nth element).

Comment: Thank you very much! There are many calls of `getProperty()` in my code... But I don't know how it fix :)

Comment: If I create index on property that often calls - may it decrease execute time?

Comment: Depending on your use case, creating an index on certain properties might be a good idea. If you want to use an index to find certain nodes, use the http://api.neo4j.org/1.8.2/org/neo4j/graphdb/index/IndexManager.html (IndexManager)

Comment: Thanks! I try create index.

Comment: What are you think about Label (in v2.0)?

Comment: That's a great addition, but it's a totally different concept than properties. If I'm not mistaken, you use a label to label a set of nodes so conceptually this is quite different. Maybe it could fit your needs though.